# Magento - reset product per page back to default value on pageload

Tags: php, magento

Magento offers a drop down on the category page that allows a user to change the amount of products per page. I've set this up in the backend to display several values and it also allows the user to view all products. By default my category page should display 9 products. but after I change the value using the drop down menu it keeps the new value even if I change the category. 
does anybody know how magento handles this? is this stored in the sesssion? I couldn't find any option in the backend to reset the value to the default value on pageload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can track it down, the user's last selection is stored in the session by the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` controller. If you want to disable that you could override the `getLimit()` method by subclassing the controller in an own class.

I personally think though it's unwanted behaviour from a user's point of view. In fact, if you reset it to a certain value it will be reset on each request, also when the user pages through the category. If you always want to show only 9 products without giving the user any choice in that you can override that by modifying/overriding `catalog.xml` or by setting it from your `local.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your installed Magento theme has the products per category number hard coded in and doesn't read this from the Magento config. Temporarily revert your theme to the default and see if the products per category changes.